# button image not changing after click in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created buttons for rating purpose like

```
var distance : CGFloat! = 0.0
for var i = 1 ;i <= 5;++i {
    var profRateBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    profRateBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(235 + distance,266,20,20))
    profRateBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "star.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    profRateBtn.tag = i
    profRateBtn.addTarget(self, action: "doProfRate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(profRateBtn)
    distance = distance + 25.0 as CGFloat
}
```

its good when button display like image which set to normal state but whenever click on it, not change image which is star filled

I am already find this on different question and also apply different solutions which given but can not change button image after selected

button action method

```
func doProfRate(sender : UIButton){
    println("btn selected : \(sender.tag)")
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "star_fill.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
}
```

Comment: r u created above method in your viewDidLoad correct , show your button action

Comment: I have created seperate method to add buttons and call it to viewDidLoad methods

Comment: its ok no problem , show your **doProfRate** methods

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik plz show my edited que...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "star_fill.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

change into

```
 sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "star_fill.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```